# how to Invoke .exe file attached inside Advanced installer Prerequisite C# custom action

Tags: c#, windows-installer, advanced-installer

I want install c++ redistributables as a prerequisite to my MSI package, using advanced installer custom action.

I have custom action ready but how could i access prerequisite file inside custom action ?

What path i need to give to locate that c++ redistributable.

I did search in advanced installer forum but could not find anything. I am new to advanced installer.

Comment: I believe you can do this in the Prerequisites section of Advanced Installer without a custom action; not at my workstation to verify.

Comment: Exactly, use the Prerequisites section to install the redistributable, not the custom actions. From Prerequisites pager you can simply check the version you need and Advanced Installer will do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- From the `Requirements` section in the nav tree on the left, select `Prerequisites`
  [image: Requirements Section]
- From the column to the right of the nav tree, select `Packages`
  [image: Select Packages]
- Scroll down to the `Visual Studio` section in the `Predefined Prerequisites` list box on the right side of the screen and select the redistributable you wish to include in your installer
  [image: Select the redistributable to include]

Note the search box marked `Filter prerequisites` at the top right for convenience.

After that you'll be prompted to download and include it in the MSI and there are additional configuration options.